# Is it possible to create Tumbling Windows in Flink using a timestamp coming in Input Stream. If yes then How?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have been trying to use Tumbling window on a Flink-Kafka consumer. Flink will be taking input from KafkaStream in Json format :

```
>{"eventGroup":"1121212" , "eventTime":"2020-01-02T13:43:43"}
>{"eventGroup":"1121212" , "eventTime":"2020-01-02T13:43:44"}
>{"eventGroup":"1121213" , "eventTime":"2020-01-02T13:43:48"}
```

I want to group this stream by eventGroup for all values of eventTime lying between say 2020-01-02T13:40:00 to 2020-01-02T13:44:59 .
Is such functionality supported by flink Tumbling Windows ? If yes then a Sample code / procedure will be great help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#tumbling-windows

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, but see https://training.ververica.com/lessons/windows.html for a tutorial and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is very common. You want to add a [timestamp extractor](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_timestamp_extractors.html) that makes the timestamp of your events known to Flink. If you use [event time processing](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/event_time.html), your tumbling window will behave as you expect it.